# Why doesn't Safari 13 paint/render outline on focus when transition is used

Tags: css, safari, focus, css-transitions, outline

Focusing on the button in the example below in safari 13.0.5 will not show the outline until you force a repaint (for example by changing the screen size)

Works fine in other browsers

Is there any hacks to get the outline to show up in Safari for this case?

```css
button {
  width: 10em;
  height: 3em;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

button:focus {
  outline : 2px blue dashed;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Button</button>
```

Interestingly, a large enough negative offset for the outline will bypass this bug.

Unfortunately that may not work in all my cases so I am hoping for a better answer.

```css
button {
  width: 10em;
  height: 3em;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

button:focus {
  outline : 2px blue dashed;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Safari 13.1 this issue is no longer reproducible!

Answer (score 0):

Thats a known safari issue.
The problem is, that you can't focus the button element in safari.
It's not even possible with the `tabindex` attribute.

See some resources:
[resource 1](https://gist.github.com/cvrebert/68659d0333a578d75372)
[resource 2](https://forum.webflow.com/t/focus-state-on-buttons-does-not-show-up-in-safari/42858/2)

A, maybe, possible solution could be something like this (change the button element to, for example, a div with a class):

```css
.button {
  width: 10em;
  height: 3em;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

.button:focus {
  outline : 2px blue dashed;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button" tabindex="0">Button</div>
```

Even in this example, you have to set the `tabindex` attribute for safari..

Comment: Don't think it has anything to do with focusing.  The button is indeed focused (check `document.activeElement`)

This bug can also be seen with a hover style instead of a focus one.

Comment: if you change `.button:focus` to `.button:focus, .button:active` you see changes, even in safari.
So for me, it looks like a `:focus` bug for buttons

Comment: It also doesn't work for me with an active state instead of a focus state.  The outline still doesn't show up